# Should a proxy ever change the HTTP request URI

Tags: http, redirect, proxy

According to RFC2616, the absoluteURI form is REQUIRED when the request is being made to a proxy.

So lets say I have scenario in which my HTTP GET request is going through a proxy:
GET /test.html HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com

Proxy forwards the request with request uri as:
http://example.com/test.html

Should there ever be a case in which the proxy forwards the request uri as:
/test.html

The reason I am asking is because some servers have different redirection policies, which include the original URI, so basically the redirection location becomes:
(As an example)
http://example.com/test.htmlhttp://example.com/redirect.html
So the redirection becomes incorrect.

Just wondering if it should be the proxies job to account for this?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So lets say I have scenario in which my HTTP GET request is going through a proxy: GET /test.html HTTP/1.1 Host: example.com

This would not be a valid request to a proxy. That must be the full URL, so the request should be:

```
GET http://example.com/test.html HTTP/1.1
```

On receiving this, the proxy making a request to the origin server should indeed pass it on to `example.com` as:

```
GET /test.html HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

So yes, a proxy not only should but MUST pass on a different request URI from the one it received. (With an exception for the case where it is talking to another proxy.)

> so basically the redirection location becomes: (As an example) http://example.com/test.htmlhttp://example.com/redirect.html

A server that didn't recognise an absolute URL in a request and treated it as a relative URL would be behaving incorrectly. As [RFC 7230 states](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.2):

> To allow for transition to the absolute-form for all requests in some
> future version of HTTP, a server MUST accept the absolute-form in
> requests, even though HTTP/1.1 clients will only send them in
> requests to proxies.